# How do I test the presence of a <title> tag containing the string "sample" in Sinatra with Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

Here is my code.

main.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :sample
end
```

spec/app_spec.rb

```
require File.expand_path '../spec_helper.rb', __FILE__

describe "My Sinatra Application" do
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require File.expand_path '../../main.rb', __FILE__

module RSpecMixin
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  def app() Sinatra::Application end
end

RSpec.configure { |c| c.include RSpecMixin }
```

views/sample.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>sample</title>
</head>
</html>
```

Maybe, I should write something to spec/main_spec.rb

but I don't know what I should write.